# Kaspersky is uploading big chunks of data to a local server

Tags: malware, antivirus, spyware, antimalware, kaspersky

Kaspersky is uploading huge chunks of data to a local server! Please help me explain this!!
[image: Network Watcher]

[image: Kaspersky Telemetry]

[image: Usage Details]

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of some backup part which kaspersky takes for the files in quarantine, So that whenever required you can get back your files.

Comment: There are no backups! even though it would not send about three megabytes of data in less than an hour! every hour when it is connected!!

Comment: Then It might be a part of UDS (Urgent Detection System). A hash of a file is sent out to the cloud to actually check if its part of "Silent Detection" or not. The detection rules are configured by KL in real time and are distributed to the clients right away without having to wait for another "Signature Update Cycle". Apart from this, I am guessing submitting an official ticket with KL will provide more information via my.kaspersky.com

Comment: I checked but it was not the UDS!